# Nuxt 404 pages appears broken on generate, works fine when running dev

Tags: nuxt.js

I have my nuxt error page living here

[image: living inside of layouts folder]

My Nuxt.config has the relevant fallback behaviour of

```
generate: {
    fallback: '404.html',
    ...
```

When I run `nuxt` the 404 works properly (dev purposes). However, when I generate it with `nuxt generate` and then use `nuxt serve` it appears as if only the html is rendered. All state is inaccessible and I get errors. The 404 redirect "works" but in a broken way with lots of console errors. Anyone have any idea why there's a difference and how to go about resolving it?

Comment: What are the console errors ?

Comment: Variations of `f230578.js:2 TypeError: Cannot read property 'start_over' of undefined` etc. These are because I am trying to access state like `this.$store.state.root`

Comment: what if you try "this.$store.state?.root?.yourOtherProperty" ?

Comment: @DamianPerez That would work to hide the error, but I need it to work :) In all other parts of the app, the components get to access state nicely, just the 404 seems broken (and ONLY when I generate, in dev mode it works smoothly)

Comment: Is there 404 errors ( in loadling css or js files ? )

Comment: No, the only 404 error is when you hit a route that does not exist, which sends you to the error page, and then, well, then this